# Javascript JSON not working after parsing

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need to get graph generated from Mysql database with help of PHP. I got nice application from (http://canvasjs.com). So, I created my own JSON format in variable **element** from PHP SESSION. It gies me no error when debugged, but no result.

Line number 34 - 37 gives me graph if I don't comment them. When comment them and replace with my own JSON which is variable **element** and does not give me graph. Gives me blank page.

I am new to JSON. Help me out with this.

Following are my codes.

```
var array = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["r_array"]); ?>;

var count = 0;
var element = '';
var title = 'Malware lab, TCRC, CTA';

for( var i in array) {

    if ( count == 0 ) {
        element += ‘{y: ‘+array[i]+’,’+’ indexLabel: “‘+i+'”}';
    } else {
       element += ‘, {y: ‘+array[i]+’,’+’ indexLabel: “‘+i+'”}';
    }
    count++;
 }

 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(“chartContainer”,
 {
     title: {
        text: title
     },
 data: [
        { type: type,

            dataPoints: [
                   /*
                   34 {y: 2, indexLabel: “Kaka'”},
                   35 {y: 3, indexLabel: “Blackberry”},
                   36 {y: 1, indexLabel: “Windows Phone”},
                   37 {y: 5, indexLabel: “Others”},*/

                   element,
            ]
    }
   ]
});
chart.render();

Dumped array of $_SESSION["r_array"] as following
Array (
    [Trojan] => 1
    [Malware] => 3
    [Backdoor] => 6
    [Virus] => 2
    [Bot] => 5
    [Rootkit] => 7
    [Worm] => 5
)
```

Comment: Can you show the dump of `$_SESSION["r_array"]` .

Comment: try this --> var array = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["r_array"]); ?>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo need to pass array in correct Way

Use another variable `datapoints = [];`

and the push object into that array

```
    var datapoints = [];

    for( var i in array) {
            datapoints.push({ y : array[i] , indexLabel : i});
     }
```

and then use it as below

```
     var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(“chartContainer”,
     {
         title: {
            text: title
         },
     data: [
            { type: type,

                dataPoints: datapoints
        }
       ]
    });
    chart.render();
```

Answer (score 1):

`element` must be an array, you are trying to create it as a string(with syntax errors)

```
var array = <? php echo json_encode($_SESSION["r_array"]); ?> ;

var count = 0;
var element = [];
var title = 'Malware lab, TCRC, CTA';

for (var i in array) {
    element.push({
        y: array[i],
        indexLabel: i
    })
    count++;
}

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title: {
        text: title
    },
    data: [{
        type: type,

        dataPoints: element
    }]
});
chart.render();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/494z3g3g/)

Comment: Thanx it worked... too So array in javascript is equal to JSON?

Comment: @user3181614 json is an (almost) subset of javascript. The j in json stands for javascript. It was always the intention that you can just `eval()` a json string in javascript.